# 'id' could not be resolved ..?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

i am using EF 4.1 and when I use the following code i get an error:

'id' could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly. Near simple identifier, line 6, column 1.

c#

```
    foreach (Person Profile in _ProfilesRepository.GetProfiles(filterExpression.ToString(), sortingName, request.SortingOrder.ToString(), request.PageIndex, request.RecordsCount, request.PagesCount.HasValue ? request.PagesCount.Value : 1))
                {
//the error happens here when it comes back from the GetProfiles call : (
                    response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(Convert.ToString(Profile.ID), new List<object>()
                    {
                        Profile.Name,
                        Profile.JobTitle,
                        Profile.Type
                    }));
                }


     public IQueryable<Person> GetProfiles(string filterExpression, string sortExpression, string sortDirection, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int pagesCount)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterExpression))
                    return db.persons.Where(filterExpression).OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
                else
                    return db.persons.OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pagesCount * pageSize);
                    //return db.persons;

            }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens in `GetProfiles` but is revealed when you iterate over its results. What's in the `filterExpression`?

Answer (score 0):

The message appears when using `orderBy("fieldname asc/desc")`

```
db.persons.OrderBy(sortExpression + " " + sortDirection)
```

When I try to use `orderBy` using `lambda expression` it's working normally, no error message.

```
db.persons.OrderBy(x=>x.FieldName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This, add "it" before your short expression/fieldname :

> OrderBy("it."+sortExpression + " " + sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex *
>   PageSize).Take(pageSize); OrderBy("it."+sortExpression + " " +
>   sortDirection).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pagesCount * pageSize);